# Visualforce remoting: Parameter length does not match remote action

Tags: javascript, apex-code, visualforce

I am trying to pass two strings to my controller using JS Remoting in my VF page.

In my VF page I'm calling a javascript method using the `onclick` event handler from a checkbox:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!part.selected}" disabled="{!IF(part.selected == true, true, false)}" onclick="getParamValues('{!part.contactId}','{!part.contactName}');">
```

Here is the javascript function:

```
function getParamValues(whoid, whoname) {
    CallReportControllerExtension.getWhoId(whoid);
    CallReportControllerExtension.getWhoName(whoname);
}
```

And here are my methods in the controller:

```
@RemoteAction
public static String getWhoId(String id) {
    system.debug('*********************** we are inside the getWhoId method');
    paramWhoId = id;
    return paramWhoId;  
} 

@RemoteAction
public static String getWhoName(String name) {
    system.debug('*********************** we are inside the getWhoName method');
    paramWhoName = name;
    return paramWhoName;
}
```

In my debug, the action methods are never entered.

What does the error mean?  How can I pass the strings to the controller methods?

Answer (score 4):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting_example.htm

Here is the simple syntax as pointed in above link.Syntax error i feel in your case .

Lets resolve this with proper syntax

```
function getParamValues(whoid, whoname) {

     Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.CallReportControllerExtension.getWhoId}',
        whoid, 
        function(result, event){
            if (event.status) {
                alert('RESULT WHOID',result);

            } 
        }, 
        {escape: true}
    );

     Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.CallReportControllerExtension.getWhoName}',
        whoname, 
        function(result, event){
            if (event.status) {
                alert('RESULT WHONAME',result);

            } 
        }, 
        {escape: true}
    );
}
```

In fact you can combine these and send as List as well and return as List and then parse the same .